# How to make get request from ktor to 3rd party?

Tags: rest, kotlin, backend, ktor

I need to make get requests from my Ktor server to another 3rd party rest api,
and from my app i will make request to my Ktor server.

How can i do that?

Comment: Use ktor-client: https://ktor.io/docs/create-client.html

Answer (score 1):

You need the ktor client for that.

The ktor client allows you to make requests and handle responses.

For example:

```
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.client.statement.*
import io.ktor.http.*

val response: HttpResponse = client.request("https://ktor.io/") {
    method = HttpMethod.Get
}
```

But for more information and examples you can look at ktor's [documetation](https://ktor.io/docs/request.html).